# How I can export an XML file in R?

Tags: xml, r, file, export

I want to export a XML file and then open it with AnyLogic (the extension of AnyLogic is alp (also xml)). However, the XML file (simulation model) is static, changing only a few parameters. How could export the file to XML format? I have seen many ways to do it but I have not yet succeeded. In my case it would be more simple to export a string variable that contains all the XML (because the file varies little).
For example, if I have a variable MyData = '..........' as I get the contents of that variable is written to a file in XML format?
Thank you.

Comment: `XML::saveXML` as well if going oldschool

Comment: @RichardScriven heh. `XML2` is riddled with memory leaks and pretty heavyweight for what most folks need (emphasis on most). btw: this might help SO folks with XPath stuff http://rud.is/b/2016/01/13/cobble-xpath-interactively-with-the-xmlview-package/

Comment: @hrbrmstr - `xmlview` seems like a cool package.  I'll have to check it out.

Comment: Sorry but I am noob in this language, I can't import the libraries xml and xml_view,                                   /////   library(xml)
Error in library(xml) : there is no package called ‘xml’ Do you know why?

Comment: Case matters.  Write "XML" (capital letters) and "xml2" (lower case)

Comment: Thanks but I still can not import libraries and xmlview xml2. I have tried: library(xml2)
library(xmlview)  but the result is the same; Error in library(xml2) : there is no package called ‘xml2’

Comment: In this moment, I have a String xml = '...........', now I do: doc <- xmlParse(xml), thus, I have a document xml, but How I can export? I try write.table and write.foreign but it doesn't work, I thin the solution is write.xml but I can`t import the library, can you help me?